I am not able the call a speechSynthesis function in a composable in nuxt 3
I am trying to call a function containing  SpeechSynthesis and the function is  contained in a nuxt3 composable. I want to call it from a simple button click but I don't hear anything.
The composable function runs ok when i just call it ie mySpeak() and the button click runs a simple function but I cant combine the two. I have tried many ideas but to no avail
<script setup>
const count = ref(0);
const mySpeakExt = () => {
    count.value++
}

if (import.meta.client) {
    const { utterance, mySpeak } = compBldSpeak() //run function and extract objects
    mySpeak() //only works in the client as it needs the window object.This runs ok
    const speak = () => { //helper for the button but does not run on @click 
        count.value++
        mySpeak()
    }
}

</script>

//Extra composable file in the composable folder
export
const compBldSpeak=()=>{ //compBld is exported as a function. It returns two values
      const utterance = new  SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello hello hello")
      function mySpeak(){window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance)}
  return {utterance,mySpeak}//return an object
 } 

<template>
    <p>page speak</p>
    <button @click="mySpeakExt"> myCount</button>
    <p>{{ count }}</p>
    <button @click="speak"> speak</button>
</template>


As a rule of thumb for myself if a function relies on the window object or any other client runtime then it is likely to break.
